# Comments show up in database, but only show up on my index page after a refresh

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have AJAX, PHP, jquery, and mySQL in this very simple website I'm trying to make. All there is is a text area that sends data to the database and uses ajax\jquery to display that data onto the index page. For some reason though, I press submit and the data goes to the database, but I have to refresh the page myself to see that data on the page. I'm assuming that the problem has to do with my AJAX JQuery or even some mistake in the index. Also, when I type the text into the text area and press submit, the text remains in the textarea until I refresh the page. Haha, sorry if this is such a noob question.. I'm trying to learn. Thanks so much

Here is the AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".submit").click(function() 
{
var comment = $("#comment").val();
var post_id = $("#post").val(); 
var dataString = '&comment=' + comment
if(comment=='')
{
alert('Fill something in please!');
}
else
{
$("#flash").show();
$("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="noworries.jpg" /> ');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "commentajax.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html){

 $("ol#update").append(html);
 $("ol#update li:last").fadeIn("slow");
 $("#flash").hide();
}
});
}return false;
}); });
</script>
```

Here is the index\form area:

```
<body>
<div id="container"><img src="banner.jpg" width="890" height="150" alt="title" /></div>
<id="update" class="timeline">
<div id="flash"></div>
<div id="container">
<form action="#" method="post">
<textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="35" rows="4"></textarea><br />
<input name="submit" type="submit" class="submit" id="submit" value=" Submit Comment " /><br />
</form>
</div>
<id="update" class="timeline">
<?php
include('config.php');
//$post_id value comes from the POSTS table
$prefix="I'm happy when";
$sql=mysql_query("select * from comments order by com_id desc");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$comment=$row['com_dis'];
?>
<!--Displaying comments-->
<div id="container">
<class="box">
<?php echo "$prefix $comment"; ?>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Here is my commentajax.php

```
<?php 
include('config.php');
if($_POST)
{
$comment=$_POST['comment'];
$comment=mysql_real_escape_string($comment);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments(com_id,com_dis) VALUES ('NULL', '$comment')");
}

?>

<li class="box"><br />
<?php echo $comment; ?>
</li>
```

I'm sorry for so much code but I just started learning this four days ago and this is probably one of the last bugs until the website is functional.

Comment: I would recommend getting Firefox and firebug, so you can see the actual ajax response, and do a little debugging that way... have you tried `alert(html);` in your success function?

Comment: to delete the contain of the textarea after sending the info, simply use $('#textarea-id').val('');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is this? (copied from your code)

```
<id="update" class="timeline">
```

and

```
<class="box">
```

you have tags here that don't exist in html, and I believe it is the root of your problem.

when you say

```
 $("ol#update")
```

in your JQuery, you are trying to find an ordered list tag with an id of update, which would look like this...

```
<ol id="update"></ol>
```

but there is no tag that looks like this in your page. perhaps you need to replace `<id="update" class="timeline">` with `<ol id="update" class="timeline"></ol>`. if this is what you are looking for, please select the check mark next to this answer. thanks!